# Difficulty upgrading php7 to php8

Tags: wordpress

I have difficulties on upgrading my site to php8.
I got errors from my function.php with this code here mentioned.
Warning: Undefined array key "artikel_categorie" in.
Can someone pls advise how to modify php??

my code is

```
function custom_taxonomy_query( $query ) {
     if ($query->query['artikel_categorie'] == 'keukenvan' || $query->query['artikel_categorie'] == 'keukenover') {
        if (isset($_GET['pr']) && !empty($_GET['pr'])) {
            $search_product_title = stripslashes(urldecode($_GET['pr']));
            $products = get_posts([
                'post_type'  => 'product',
                'title' => $search_product_title,
            ]);
            if (count($products) == 1) {
                $search_product = current($products);
                $query->set( 'meta_key', 'artikel_products_artikel_products__product' );
                $query->set( 'meta_value', $search_product->ID );
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: change the first if in this:   `if ( isset($query->query['artikel_categorie']) && ( $query->query['artikel_categorie'] == 'keukenvan' || $query->query['artikel_categorie'] == 'keukenover') )`

Comment: Thank you so much!!! It did the trick. I am really bad at php so thank you so much for your answer!!

Comment: You're welcome, btw the problem is that in the $query->query array the is not a "artikel_categorie" key so, before checking it's value, it is nessary checking if that key exists. If you are using php 7+ version look the ?? notation it permits to access safely array values or properties on objects